# Clipping of a negative feedback amplifier

Tags: amplifier, feedback, bias, voltage-clipping

I need help solving the following exercise from my book.
[image]

I am not very knowledgeable in analyzing biasing circuits but I have understood the following:
\$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are feedback resistors. This is a voltage amplifier. \$R_L\$ is the load. The output stage of the amplifier is a **npn-transistor**. the input stage is a differential stage and the peak output voltage is \$v_L = 1.5V\$.

Should I know assume that npn-transistor is a switch and check the two cases? Or how should I proceed. Do I assume anything else about this circuit like that the base currents are 0 and that the base voltages across the differential amplifier stage is zero?

Comment: "The peak output voltage is 1.5V". Use that info, and analyse the circuit for both positive and negative peaks.

Comment: What is the load current at clipping when PNP is OFF?  And the output stage of the amplifier is a PNP-transistor not NPN.

Comment: Also, from which book you have this exercise?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what the load current is there. 1mA = current from feedback resistors + current from load resistor (due to KCL).

Comment: @G36 Book: http://tinyurl.com/ya3vjpu9

Comment: Swedish book in English? Can you solve this if you ignore R1 and R2 and remove the PNP transistor from the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

- output stage is the PNP with 1mA sink, not NPN.
- if Ve =-2.5V and we assume Vbe of 0.6 with IE=0 causing saturation of input left NPN such that Vce =~0

  - then \$V_L* R1/(R1+R2)=Vb\$
  - for \$V_L=+/-1.5V solve for RL
- if -1.5V and 1mA sink with 11K bias to gnd + Ibe and Iload , is this what is asked? what is Iload max? 1.5V/11k=0.136mA thus -1.5v/0.863mA =1.73K min R load

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! Is $V_e$ the voltage at the emitter of the pnp transistor? I thought that that should be 2.5V and not -2.5. Why is it negative?

Comment: it's a bipolar supply +/-2.5V to allow 0V input/output but 1mA Sink is on Vee (-) so I need to correct my error in equation 2

Comment: By "bipolar supply" do you mean that there is basically two DC sources with a ground between them? pnp transistor has 2.5V at its emitter (which is the one with the arrow). -Does the 2.5V originate from the DC source below the ground symbol or am I supposed to look at the source above ground symbol? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2 equal supplies with centre gnd 1 above + and 1 below gnd with - to bottom rail

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. Now, is that -2.5V coming from the bottom supply which is below ground?

Comment: ground is symbolic only to mean 0V locally and not earth or any other reference.  I could be floating as shown but all V ate referenced to this symbol.. My answer is incomplete/incorrect BTW

Comment: But where is that -2.5 "measured" like; do you measure it in the node where \$ R_2 \$ and \$ R_L \$ meet? If that is the case, would its still be -2.5 if I removed the supply above ground?

Comment: all gnd symbols are joined , common, "logically" but does Not need to say how. The are usually close but details depend on application.  so gnd symbol by definition is 0V

Comment: I get that with the grounds and sources now but I don't know how you get -2.5V at the emitter since the current source \$ 1 mA \$ acts like infinite impedance I have been told.

Comment: I think the PNP can easily pull-up 1mA but the 1mA sink cannot pull down to -1.5V max if load to ground is pulling up more than 0.863 mA so negative output has an obvious limit. positive limit depends on \$\beta*I_E\$ assumed to be more since Re is not given.  I may misunderstand but seems like a trick question on polarity